# PDF byte stream greater then 1.56 MB not working in chrome

Tags: html, pdf, arrays, embed

I am generating in-memory PDF's on the server and want to send the result as a byte stream to be displayed as a PDF on a web page.Below both options work.
File stream is encoded in base64.

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,@Model.Preview" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

OR

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64, @Model.Preview" type="application/pdf" />
```

Both display the Pdf's in FireFox and chrome. However when Byte[] size exceed 1.56MB it is not displayed in Chrome. I only see a white screen.It works fine in Firefox for bigger size even 9MB. Not sure why it is not working in chrome or if there is another batter way of doing this.

Comment: <embed src="data:application/pdf;base64, @Model.Preview" type="application/pdf" />

Comment: <object data="data:application/pdf;base64,@Model.Preview" type="application/pdf"></object>

Comment: checked the chrome debug console for errors/warnings?

Comment: I do see an error in Network tab, it shows the contents of  src attribute.byte stream added at the end. Status: (data), Size : 0B. no more info.